# Google Apps Script get response from external API

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-apps-script

I'm using a google apps script to get data from an external API.

This is the code I'm using:

```
function cenas(){
 var url='https://app.ecwid.com/api/v1/XXX/orders';
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Access token or API key not found in request parameters
```

I know I must provide the secret authentification key. But how do I include that in the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a second parameter to [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)) for params. Inside those params you can pass things such as your method and headers - which is where you would pass your Authorization header.

Depending on your params, your code would probably look something like:

```
var headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
};  
var params = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'headers': headers,
  'contentType': 'application/json'
}
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
```